# How to change default program open .rar file which select open file by explorer.exe?

Tags: file, explorer, rar

I tried open .rar file with window explorer of explorer.exe when choose in select program open file. After, I can't open this file by rar program and don't change program open for this file. How to restore default open program file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it..

follow the below steps

1. Open Default Programs by clicking the Start button, or Go to Control Panel ->Default Programs->
2. Click the Associate a file type or protocol with a program., or simply type the url Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations in control panel window.

3.Scroll down and  select the type Rar which we are going to revert the default open with program.

1. Click Change program.
2. Click the program Rar which is supposed to use as default program

Answer (score 1):

Go to default app/settings, scroll down to the bottom and select "reset" this should return the directories to their recommended settings.

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "Default" in start menu and click on "Set your default programs". Click on WinRAR or the software you want to use. Click on "Choose defaults for this program" and check .rar file.